# Filtering <img> elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

When I run same code without images like giving some text on li gives me the result but when I put the images. It doesnot work. 
Any suggestions here--`

Here Iam trying with list but in actual project I have a table with 3 rows categorized with 3 different class name with 4 images each in table row.
How can I fetch only selected elements group

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  //remove selected class from all buttons
  $("button").removeClass("selected");

  //add selected class only to clicked button
  $(this).addClass("selected");

  //get data type filter
  var dataFilter = $(this).data('filter');

  //if data filter is all show all of them
  if(dataFilter == "all") {
      $(".elements li").show();
  }
  else
  {
    //else hide all of them and show only the one with correct data filter
    $(".elements li").hide();
    $("." + dataFilter).show();
  }
});
```

```css
li{
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filters">
  <button class="selected" data-filter="all">Show All</button>
  <button data-filter="type-one">Show One</button>
  <button data-filter="type-two">Show Two</button>
</div>
<tr class="people">
  <td><img src="./thumbs/anil_tn.jpg" alt="anil1" class="gallery_image"></td>
  <td><img src="./thumbs/kapri_tn.jpg" alt="anil2" class="gallery_image"></td>
  <td><img src="./thumbs/me.jpg" alt="anil3" class="gallery_image"></td>
  <td><img src="./thumbs/pandey_tn.jpg" alt="anil4" class="gallery_image"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="nature">
  <td><img src="./thumbs/best_tn.jpg" alt="anil5" class="gallery_image"></td>
  <td><img src="./thumbs/ny_tn.jpg" alt="anil6" class="gallery_image"></td>
  <td><img src="./images/talo.jpg" alt="anil7" class="gallery_image"></td>
  <td><img src="./images/turku.jpg" alt="anil8" class="gallery_image"></td>
</tr>
```

?

Comment: In your example here, it seems to work. Please, if you have a problem with your code, post the code that is really with some issue, so we can reproduce the error instead of viewing the code that is working well. See [mcve]

Comment: but it is not working on mine. That is the code..

Comment: So maybe I understood wrong... What is the desired output? What is the issue you are facing? Please, be more clear with your problem

Comment: Iam not getting the output. When I click show one or show two it doesn't respond in the case while putting images but works fine when I put text..

Comment: how to do it when i have 2 table rows with different categories. when I click show 1 it should only show the <td> of selected one while hiding others

Comment: Are you sure, the images' src points to actual images, that can be fetched?

Comment: I don't see any `<td>` or table in your example above,  that's why I said about the real code that you are using...  
Also, check img `src` as said by @PoulBak

Comment: <tr class="people">
      <td><img src="./thumbs/anil_tn.jpg" alt="anil" class="gallery_image"></td>
      <td><img src="./thumbs/kapri_tn.jpg" alt="anil" class="gallery_image"></td>
      <td><img src="./thumbs/me.jpg" alt="anil" class="gallery_image"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="nature">
      <td><img src="./thumbs/best_tn.jpg" alt="anil" class="gallery_image"></td>
      <td><img src="./thumbs/ny_tn.jpg" alt="anil" class="gallery_image"></td>
     </tr>

Comment: These images are real images, some I took from internet while some I click myself. You can modify the images differently but I got stuck on this. I wanted to apply the same j.s logic here in table where I have multiple images but couldn't do it...Iam new in javascript--

Comment: do you have any error in the console? could you please let us know if you are getting any error.

Comment: don't post as comment, please, it is unreadable. use the [edit] option and edit your question, let it more clear to avoid it to be closed and add this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?
Where the button filter for `people` or for `nature` and then the table is the `.elements` and each row is the `class` that should be filtered.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("button").removeClass("selected");

  $(this).addClass("selected");

  var dataFilter = $(this).data('filter');

  if(dataFilter == "all") {
      $(".elements tr").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $(".elements tr").hide();
    $("." + dataFilter).show();
  }
});
```

```css
li{
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filters">
  <button class="selected" data-filter="all">Show All</button>
  <button data-filter="people">Show One</button>
  <button data-filter="nature">Show Two</button>
</div>
<table class="elements">
  <tr class="people">
    <td><img src="./thumbs/anil_tn.jpg" alt="anil1" class="gallery_image"></td>
    <td><img src="./thumbs/kapri_tn.jpg" alt="anil2" class="gallery_image"></td>
    <td><img src="./thumbs/me.jpg" alt="anil3" class="gallery_image"></td>
    <td><img src="./thumbs/pandey_tn.jpg" alt="anil4" class="gallery_image"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="nature">
    <td><img src="./thumbs/best_tn.jpg" alt="anil5" class="gallery_image"></td>
    <td><img src="./thumbs/ny_tn.jpg" alt="anil6" class="gallery_image"></td>
    <td><img src="./images/talo.jpg" alt="anil7" class="gallery_image"></td>
    <td><img src="./images/turku.jpg" alt="anil8" class="gallery_image"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```